# Type Mismatch on one machine

Tags: vba

I wrote some code to scrape data from a website. I've tested it on 5 difference machines with different versions of excel and it all works fine. But on the intended users machine we get type mismatch error.The code fails at the last line below.

```
Sub LogIn()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim iDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim tableSection As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim tableRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim tableCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim smallCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCounter As Integer

iRow = 0
    Do
     iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop Until Cells(iRow, 5) = ""
 Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(iRow, 6)).ClearContents

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = False

ie.navigate ("https://www.howdidido.com/")

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set iDoc = ie.document
```

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're using early binding to the HTML libraries (which is fine). It's possible the machine getting the error has a different (i.e. not up to date) version of that library.

Comment: So, it fails on `Set iDoc = ie.document`?  Have you tried taking the type off `iDoc` (or declaring it as Variant)?  Kind of a pain for development, but may get around if the underlying class id is different for the object type.  There may be some differences in the component version.

Comment: Declared iDoc as variant today and the code now works on the users machine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code and it is working alright. Maybe it can help you (seems as two loops and doEvents are needed for the ready state completes).

```
Dim iDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCounter As Integer

Dim i As Long
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
IE.Visible = True
'Define URL
URL = "https://www.automateexcel.com/excel/"
'Navigate to URL
IE.Navigate URL
' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."
' Wait while IE loading...
'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
'Webpage Loaded
Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"
Set iDoc = IE.Document

'Unload IE
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing
```